# Inconsistent indexing of subplots returned by `pandas.DataFrame.plot` when changing plot kind

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, figure

I know that, this issue is known and was already discussed. But I am encountering a strange behaviour, may be someone has idea why:
When I run this:

```
plot = df.plot(kind="box", subplots=True, layout= (7,4), fontsize=12, figsize=(20,40))
fig = plot[0].get_figure()
fig.savefig(str(path) + "/Graphics/" + "Boxplot_all.png")
plot
```

It works just fine.

When I change the kind plot to ="line", it gives that known error... but why? I don't get it...

```
plot = df.plot(kind="line", subplots=True, layout= (7,4), fontsize=12, figsize=(20,40))
fig = plot[0].get_figure()
fig.savefig(str(path) + "/Graphics/" + "Line_all.png")
plot
```

Thanks for your ideas and hints.
Cheers Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an inconsistency in Pandas. According to their [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), indeed, the `DataFrame`'s method `.plot()` should return

> `matplotlib.axes.Axes` or `numpy.ndarray` of them

This is true if you choose the `kind="line"` option:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                      columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

>>> plot=df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(2,2),kind="line")

>>> type(plot)
numpy.ndarray

>>> plot.shape
(2, 2)
```

But not with `kind="box"`, where you get a pandas Series:

```
>>> plot=df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(2,2),kind="box")

>>> type(plot)
pandas.core.series.Series

>>> plot.shape
(3,)
```

So, if using `kind="line"`, you have to access a 2D array, so you should use:

```
fig = plot[0,0].get_figure()
```

Comment: Hello David, thank you very much! Wow, now working like a bee!